# "As I used to" vs "Like I used to"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In sentences such as:

> We could go down to the fishing village, just ______ we used to.

Is there a *right* or *wrong* preposition to use, between "as" and "like"?

What would be the difference?

Comment: No, they are equivalent, and belong to an informal style. Note that you could also say _... (just) the same as we used to_.

Comment: @tchrist The sentence template used in this question is more accepting of both *as* and *like* than the possible duplicate you found. I think this question stands better on its own than as a duplicate of the other. (Also, the other uses *as if*, not just *as*.)